# Sublist Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

I am implementing my own LinkedList class.

For sublist(int a,int b function) method,mycode doesn't work properly.it should return sublist of list according to (a and b indexes)(which i succeed) also after this method if any change is made on sublist also list must be effected(not succeed).for example if i execute
`(list.sublist(1,4)).clear` :list elements from 1 to 4  should clear also.
My code is:

```
public List<E> subList(int arg0, int arg1) {

    ArrayList<E> ar = new ArrayList<E>(); 

    ListIterator myiter=listIterator(arg0);

    int k = arg1 - arg0 + 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        ar.add((E) myiter.next());
    }

    List <E> sublist=new GITLinkedList(ar);
    return sublist;
}
```

Comment: i declare int just before for loop as a counter

Comment: oh oh forget about it then... :)

Comment: why is the counter pre-incremented (`++i`)?

Comment: @EliranMalka Why do you think it is a problem using pre-increment?

Comment: it could manifest a logical issue if the counter is incremented before its assignment. try post-incrementation.

Comment: @EliranMalka the ++i is executed only after the i. step of the loop is done so it can't be a problem. Please use (@)name to reply a comment.

Comment: @user1070935 Is there a reason you're overriding the `subList` method? This is already well implemented in all Java `List` classes and includes propagating changes to the parent list, checks for concurrent modifications etc.

Comment: @EliranMalka: `for(i=0;i<k;++i)` is perfectly valid and has done its job for some decades just as expected. Not only in Java but also in other languages with support for pre/postincrement.

Comment: @EliranMalka: there is no reletation i and my problem

Comment: @user1070935 i don't want to use Java's i want to implement my own in Java just for practice

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you return a class that extends `List` and overwrites some of the internal methods to trick other classes into thinking its only a subset.

For example, in your sublist method you might do this...

```
public List<E> subList(int startPosition, int endPosition) {
    return new SmallerList(this,startPosition,endPosition);
}
```

and create a `SmallerList` class like so...

```
public class SmallerList extends List {

    List parentList = null;
    int startPosition = 0;
    int endPosition = 0;

    public SmallerList(List parentList, int startPosition, int endPosition){
        this.parentList = parentList;
        this.startPosition = startPosition;
        this.endPosition = endPosition;
    }

    // overwrite some directly to appear smaller
    public int size(){
        return endPosition-startPosition;
    }

    // overwrite others to make adjustments to the correct position in the parentList
    public void add(int index, Object object){
        parentList.add(index+startPosition,object);
    }

    // overwrite others to only search between startPosition and endPosition
    public boolean contains (Object object){
        for (int i=startPosition;i<endPosition;i++){
            if (parentList.get(i).equals(object)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // etc. for all other methods of List.
}
```

With this approach, all the methods still act on the underlying `parentList`, but any queries to `SmallerList` such as `add()`, `get()`, `contains()`, `size()`, are all tricked to thinking that they're only working on a smaller `List`

Comment: This is basically the way which `java.util.LinkedList` implements `sublist`. The JDK called it `SubList` instead of `SmallerList` though :-)

Comment: Cool, didn't know that, at least that helps to validate that my solution was a sensible idea :-)

Comment: but i think there shouldn't need any other implemantation.Sublist also must LinkedList

Comment: @user1070935: Sorry, I do not understand what you want to tell us.